draw brace on tabular table without remember overlay
I have found this great post enter lAdd a curved arrow and a bracket to a table, But I want I want is put the tabular into the same tizkpicture environment and remove the remember overly, which need two times compile to take effect.
Any other solution instead of tabular is welcome as well.
I copied the full code from the post here:
\documentclass[border=20pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][-3pt]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.5ex]\node[#1](#2){};}

\tikzset{brace/.style={decorate, decoration={brace}},
 brace mirrored/.style={decorate, decoration={brace,mirror}},
}

\newcounter{brace}
\setcounter{brace}{0}
\newcommand{\drawbrace}[3][brace]{%
 \refstepcounter{brace}
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[#1] (#2.center)--(#3.center)node[pos=0.5, name=brace-\thebrace]{};
}

\newcounter{arrow}
\setcounter{arrow}{0}
\newcommand{\drawcurvedarrow}[3][]{%
 \refstepcounter{arrow}
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw (#2.center)edge[#1]node[coordinate,pos=0.5, name=arrow-\thearrow]{}(#3.center);
}

% #1 options, #2 position, #3 text 
\newcommand{\annote}[3][]{%
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[#1] at (#2) {#3};
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{ | l | l |}
  \hline
   letter & number \\ \hline
   \tikzmark[xshift=-8pt,yshift=1ex]{x}A &  1\tikzmark[xshift=3.5em]{a} \\ \hline
   A &  2 \\ \hline
   \tikzmark[xshift=-8pt,yshift=-1ex]{y}A &  1\tikzmark[xshift=3.5em]{b} \\ \hline
   \tikzmark[xshift=-8pt,yshift=1ex]{w}B &  1 \\ \hline
   \tikzmark[xshift=-8pt,yshift=-1ex]{z}B &  2 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend left=60,-stealth]{a}{b}
\drawbrace[brace mirrored, thick]{x}{y}
\drawbrace[brace mirrored, thick]{w}{z}
\annote[right]{arrow-1}{Duplicate}
\annote[left]{brace-1}{A}
\annote[left]{brace-2}{B}
\end{document}

Output:


A matrix of nodes? The only way I can think to put an actual tabular in would be inside a node and then you'd still need markers within it and two compilations (but you'd need a different macro to do the marking). If you make it a matrix, it'll all be marked automatically.

If you use a matrix of nodes rather than a tabular, the cells become named nodes you can reference normally. For example,

\documentclass[border=20pt,png]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/715067/
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,matrix,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
  brace/.style={decorate, decoration={brace}},
  brace mirrored/.style={decorate, decoration={brace,mirror}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,nodes={text width=12.5mm,text height=1.5ex,anchor=base west}]
  {
    letter & number \\
    A   &   1  \\
    A   &   2  \\
    A   &   1  \\
    B   &   1  \\
    B   &   2  \\
  };
  \foreach \i/\j/\k in {2/4/A,5/6/B}
  \draw [brace mirrored,thick] (m.west |- m-\i-1.north) -- node [midway,left] {\k} (m.west |- m-\j-1.south);
  \draw (m-1-1.north west) -| (m-6-2.south east) -| cycle
  (m-1-1.north east) -- (m-6-1.south east)
  foreach \i in {2,3,...,6} { (m-\i-1.north west) -- (m-\i-2.north east) }
  ;
  \draw [-Latex] (m-2-2.east -| m.east) [bend left] to node [midway,right] {Duplicate} (m-4-2.east -| m.east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I've posted a screenshot. :-)

@Mico Thank you so much! I really appreciate that people are doing this for me.

@MicoAwesome, It's smart to draw the borders by draw commands. I always stuck there with nodes borders since it can not fit cell size perfectly!
